# (a: number) => {} cannot be assigned to type (a?: number) => void

Tags: typescript

```
type F = (a?: number) => void

const f: F = (a: number) => {}
```

I got the error:
Type '(a: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'F'.
Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)

But my understanding is I'm assigning a variable to a Type, which means I'm assigning  'number' to 'number | undefined', not the other way around.

And the reverse does work, no error

```
type F = (a: number) => void

const f: F = (a?: number) => {}
```

But it seems to me it should be an error, because I could give a function without any parameter to a type that requires a: number.

What did I miss? Please help me understand this

Comment: You needn't specify the type of `a` if you have already defined the argument type in `F`

Comment: const f: F = (a: number) => {} here :number is unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type definitions can only narrow down the valid call signatures for a function. If you have a function `f` and you declare it to be of type `F`, then the valid call signatures of `F` must be a subset of valid call signatures of `f`.

More concretely:
Your definition `F` allows to optionally pass in a number. That means that for any function `foo` that is of type `F`, `foo()` must be a valid call.

Your function f **requires** that you pass in a number. So `f()` is not a valid call and f cannot be of type `F`.

Regarding the reverse direction:
If `F` makes it mandatory that a number is present, then `f` can be of type `F`, as you narrow down the type of f: normally, `f()` and `f(n)` are valid calls, and by declaring `f` to be of type `F` only `f(n)` will remain available.